# jquery select videos inside div and mute them

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, html5-video

I'm trying to mute some videos when a specific button is pressed with jquery.

i have this html code

```
<button id="mute">Mute all</button>
<button id="unmute">Unmute all</button>

<div id="displayer"></div>
```

The thing is, at some point, my displayer will by filled like this:

```
<div id="displayer">
    <div id="row0" class="row">
        <div class="col-md-2">
            <video  id="recorded0" autoplay="" loop="" src="some_video" controls=""></video>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-2">
            <video  id="recorded1" autoplay="" loop="" src="some_video" controls=""></video>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-2">
            <video id="recorded2" autoplay="" loop="" src="some_video" controls=""></video>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-2">
            <video  id="recorded3" autoplay="" loop="" src="some_video" controls=""></video>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-2">
            <video  id="recorded4" autoplay="" loop="" src="some_video" controls=""></video>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-2">
            <video id="recorded5" autoplay="" loop="" src="some_video" controls=""></video>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="row1" class="row">
        <div class="col-md-2">
            <video id="recorded6" autoplay="" loop="" src="some_video" controls=""></video>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-2">
            <video id="recorded7" autoplay="" loop="" src="some_video" controls=""></video>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-2">
            <video id="recorded8" autoplay="" loop="" src="some_video" controls=""></video>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

here's my javascript code :

```
$("#mute").click(function() {
  $("#displayer > video").prop('muted', true);
});

$("#unmute").click(function() {
  $("#displayer > video").prop('muted', false);
});
```

and it doesn't work. I don't see why. Can someone help me ?

Comment: instead of `$("#displayer > video")` try `$("#displayer  video")`

Comment: Have you tried looking up CSS selectors?

Comment: @KartikeyaKhosla works great, thanks.

Comment: @gcampbell what do you mean ?

Comment: @KartikeyaKhosla but why does it behaves that way ? is it because when i declare my javascript code the html code is not filled ?

Comment: @Devz https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Getting_Started/Selectors

Answer (score 5):

$("#displayer" > video") means get all the video elements that are *immediate children* of #displayer. The only immediate children of #displayer are your div rows.

Try this instead:

```
$("#displayer video")
```